# How can I make Outlook reset the importance flag when replying or forwarding an email that was received with High Importance?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I reply to or forward a message that originally came in with *High Importance*, Outlook automatically persists that importance level when composing my outgoing email.

I rarely notice that this is set on the ribbon when composing my message, and it's not until I have hit *Send* that I realise.

Is there any way I can configure Outlook **not** to persist this setting in replies and forwards?  I would prefer to explicitly set it myself if necessary.

Comment: I don't think this feature exists yet. I have created a UserVoice entry for it: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/40707565-always-use-default-importance-when-replying-to-or